# Linux NTFS-3G General Protection Fault when using OS X in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ntfs, linux-kernel, ntfs-3g

I have an OS X virtual machine in VirtualBox on a Debian host. The disk image is located on an NTFS partition (which is not the system's root partition), mounted using NTFS-3G.

The machine was working fine for months, but now when starting it, it crashes during the boot process and syslog shows a General Protection Fault exception in the host machine kernel caused be NTFS-3G.

The same virtual machine works fine when the disk image is on an ext4 partition. Reinstalling the virtual machine made no difference (installation crashes on NTFS, succeeds on ext4).

Any idea what could be the problem, or how to debug it further? I can't find any information on what can bring NTFS-3G to cause a General Protection Fault exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82951

As 3.16 kernel end of life update to 3.17 or downgrade to 3.2 ))